# Regroup channels in Object Transforms of Graph Editor

Tags: camera, keyframes, graph-editor

As shown in the screenshot attached below, the Z location and Y rotation channels alone are present outside the 'Object Transforms' group. However, I would like the two to also be inside that group. I want it so because I find that when I set keyframes for the camera, the values for Z location and Y rotation dont change as I desire.
I would also appreciate if someone can explain what these channels control and what these groups mean, for I have not been able to comprehend much from the blender documentation. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the dopesheet and graph editor, you can select some or all channels and use the menu Channel with the "group channels" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>) and "Ungroup channels" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>) functions.

This grouping/ungrouping is useful only for organization purposes, when you have lots of curves and you want to organize them, it has no impact on their behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to group them all together. But one issue still persists: Whenever I change camera position and insert a keyframe, Z location and Y rotation dont get added as keyframe; ie, when I press 'I' the Z and Y dont change color from Orange to yellow.  How to fix this?

Comment: Is your keyset only scale? Do the others 7 channel get keyframed? Are you using the NLA editor? Does this happen even into a new file? Maybe you could try to save a copy of the file, delete everything except the camera, and if the issue persist upload this new file.